# PHP preg_split for New line with upper case and custom character

Tags: php, regex

I need to parse `.ics` file's content to import events to `MySQL database`, but in my case the descriptions of the events are long and started from a new line. That's why I need a `regular expression` to detect newlines which start in the capital letters and after them `:`. This is a default evetns code

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20181031T200000Z
DTSTAMP:20200507T084920Z
UID:Ical2b1c1757c3ad34668ba61907c0f0c280
CREATED:19000101T120000Z
DESCRIPTION:Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesettin
 g industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry standard dummy text ever sinc
 e the 1500s\, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled i
 t to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries\, b
 ut also the leap into electronic typesetting\, remaining essentially unchan
 ged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets co
 ntaining Lorem Ipsum passages\, and more recently with desktop including ve
 rsions of Lorem Ipsum.
LAST-MODIFIED:20191119T090442Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Event 2
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
```

and this is my code which returns an array parsed on each new line.

`$parsedEvent = preg_split('/\.\s*?(?=[A-Z])|(\r\n|\n|\r)/', trim($event));`

Answer (score 0):

A non-regex version which splits the file into lines and then if the first char is a space, then this is a continuation of the previous entry. 
 Otherwise split out the new entry and add it in...

```
$values = [];
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $event);
$outputValue = '';
foreach ( $lines as $line ) {
    if ( $line[0] === ' ' ) {
        $values[$outputValue] .= trim($line);
    }
    else    {
        list($key, $value) = explode(":", $line, 2);
        $values[$key] = trim($value);
        $outputValue = $key;
    }
}
```

gives...

```
Array
(
    [BEGIN] => VEVENT
    [DTSTART] => 20181031T200000Z
    [DTSTAMP] => 20200507T084920Z
    [UID] => Ical2b1c1757c3ad34668ba61907c0f0c280
    [CREATED] => 19000101T120000Z
    [DESCRIPTION] => Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry standard dummy text ever since the 1500s\, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries\, but also the leap into electronic typesetting\, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages\, and more recently with desktop including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    [LAST-MODIFIED] => 20191119T090442Z
    [LOCATION] => 
    [SEQUENCE] => 0
    [STATUS] => CONFIRMED
    [SUMMARY] => Event 2
    [TRANSP] => OPAQUE
    [END] => VEVENT
)
```

The removal of the newline and single space is as described in the [spec](https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-1-content-lines.html)

> Any sequence of CRLF followed immediately by a single linear
>   white-space character is ignored (i.e., removed) when processing the
>   content type.